# Unconstrained Optimization - Minimum Distance Between Point and Curve

Tags: calculus, optimization, regression-analysis

**Background:**

I am writing some software can fit a mathematical curve to data using different regression techniques.  I currently have Ordinary Least Squares and Least Absolute Deviations mostly implemented, and am now working on Total Least Squares.  In TLS, both x and y distances from the curve are minimized, rather than just y.

**Problem:**

In order to get my software to work, I need a closed-form solution to finding the minimum distance between a point $(x_{n}, y_{n})$ and a function $f(x)$ on an unbounded domain.  It also needs to be reasonably fast to compute (so preferably non-iterative) because this operation could possibly be carried out thousands of times during the curve fitting process.

**What I Know So Far:**

- I know that a global minimum value must exist. The distance between $(x_{n}, y_{n})$ and $(x, f(x))$ can be modeled by $\sqrt{(x_n-x)^2 + (y_n-f(x))^2}$, which I believe (from what I've read) is coercive, which implies the existence of a global minimum.
- The minimum value must be less than or equal to $|y_n - f(x_n)|$, assuming $f(x_n)$ is defined.

**My Plea:**

Can someone at least point me in a direction?

Comment: A closed-form exact solution for an arbitrary function $f$?  No such thing!

Comment: Not even if the minimum is guaranteed to exist?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $d$ with rational coefficients, and for convenience take $(x_n, y_n) = (0,0)$.  You want to minimize $g(x) = x^2 + f(x)^2$ (the square of your distance): the minimum occurs at a 
root of $g'(x) = 2 x + 2 f(x) f'(x)$, a polynomial of degree $2d-1$ which will usually be irreducible over the rationals, so the root would be an algebraic number of degree $2d-1$.  You then evaluate $g(x)$ at such a root: 
the result will again be likely to be algebraic of degree $2d-1$.  So unless you can solve polynomials of high degree in "closed form", you're not going to be able to do this exactly.

For example, try $f(x) = x^3 + x + 1$.  The minimum occurs at a root of
$6\,{x}^{5}+8\,{x}^{3}+6\,{x}^{2}+4\,x+2$, and the minimum value is a root of ${z}^{5}-2\,{z}^{4}+\frac {31}{27}{z}^{3}+{\frac {2}{27}} z -\frac{1}{27}$.  That polynomial has Galois group $S_5$, so no solution in radicals.

Comment: Would it change anything if $f(x)$ was approximated by many small line segments?

Comment: Then in general you'd have to look at each segment.  Each individually is easy, but a lot of them would take a lot of time.